# Slice all rows of a DataFrame past a certain value in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying to find a more pandorable way to get all rows of a DataFrame past a certain value in the a certain column (the `Quarter` column in this case).

I want to slice a DataFrame of GDP statistics to get all rows *past* the first quarter of 2000 (`2000q1`). Currently, I'm doing this by getting the index number of the value in the `GDP_df["Quarter"]` column that equals `2000q1` (see below). This seems way too convoluted and there must be an easier, simpler, more idiomatic way to achieve this. Any ideas?

**Current Method:**

```
def get_GDP_df():
    GDP_df = pd.read_excel(
        "gdplev.xls", 
        names=["Quarter", "GDP in 2009 dollars"], 
        parse_cols = "E,G", skiprows = 7)
    year_2000 = GDP_df.index[GDP_df["Quarter"] == '2000q1'].tolist()[0]
    GDP_df["Growth"] = (GDP_df["GDP in 2009 dollars"]
        .pct_change()
        .apply(lambda x: f"{round((x * 100), 2)}%"))
    GDP_df = GDP_df[year_2000:]
    return GDP_df
```

**Output:**

[image]

Also, after the DataFrame has been sliced, the indices now start at 212. Is there a method to renumber the indices so they start at 0 or 1?

Comment: Take a look at  `~`  [not operator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval) and [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query) for the slicing.

Comment: For index reindexing use `GDP_df = GDP_df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @n1tk Thanks, those pages were both super helpful. But is this what you mean? It still seems a bit more complex than it could be: 
`year_2000 = GDP_df.query("Quarter == '2000q1'").index.tolist()[0]` 

(after this runs, `year_2000 == 212`)

Comment: @n1tk Ah, wait a sec, this works and it is infinitely better: `GDP_df = GDP_df.query("Quarter >= '2000q1'")`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following is equivalent:

```
year_2000 = (GDP_df["Quarter"] == '2000q1').idxmax()
GDP_df["Growth"] = (GDP_df["GDP in 2009 dollars"]
  .pct_change()
  .mul(100)
  .round(2)
  .apply(lambda x: f"{x}%"))
return GDP_df.loc[year_2000:]
```

Comment: I wonder if .values.argmax() is preferable to idxmax()... and then use .iloc.

Answer (score 1):

> As pointed in the comments you can use the new *awesome* method [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query)
>   that `Query the columns of a DataFrame with a boolean expression that
>   uses the top-level pandas.eval() function to evaluate the passed
>   query` with [pandas.eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval) method that `Evaluate a Python expression
>   as a string using various backends` that uses [only Python
>   expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements).

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'ID':['101','101','101','102','102','102','102','103','103','103','103'],
            'Week':['08-02-2000','09-02-2000','11-02-2000','10-02-2000','09-02-2000','08-02-2000','07-02-2000','01-02-2000',
               '02-02-2000','03-02-2000','04-02-2000'],
            'Quarter':['2000q1','2000q2','2000q3','2000q4','2000q1','2000q2','2000q3','2000q4','2000q1','2000q2','2000q3'],
            'GDP in 2000 dollars':[15,15,10,15,15,5,10,10,15,20,11]}


def get_GDP_df():
    GDP_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data).set_index('ID')
    print(GDP_df) # for reference to see how the data is indexed, printing out to the screen
    GDP_df = GDP_df.query("Quarter >= '2000q1'").reset_index(drop=True) #performing the query() + reindexing the dataframe
    GDP_df["Growth"] = (GDP_df["GDP in 2000 dollars"]
        .pct_change()
        .apply(lambda x: f"{round((x * 100), 2)}%"))
    return GDP_df

get_GDP_df()
```

[image: Table1: SampleData read. // Table2: FinalResult with re-indexing.]